# psake msbuild error

Tags: powershell, msbuild, build, visual-studio-2008-sp1, psake

I want to build my solution using psake and msbuild (v3.5) on an x64 pc. When I execute the script I get the following error:

error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

The message is correct, the file is missing but I have installed the 32 bit version of VS 2008 and therefor it is in the folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)...'

Is there any solution to tell msbuild to use the 32 bit version, not the 64 bit version?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify what framework version is used for build. See `$framework` variable. In your case you need `$framework = '3.5×86'` at the beginning of the script.